# Index Error when creating Numpy Array from For Loop

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, indexing

The below code excerpt produces the following error at the last line

IndexError: list assignment index out of range

I'm expecting that w is an array with 3 values in it, w[0], w[1], w[2].  Do you see my error?

```
import numpy as np
n = 7
q = 0.02
pnum = 0
pden = 0
w = [(n - 1) // 2]
for i in range((n - 1) // 2):
    for m in range(5):
        pnum += (-1)**m * q**(m*(m+1)) * np.sin((2*m+1) * np.pi * i / n)
        pden += (-1)**(m+1) * q**((m+1)**2) * np.cos(2 * (m+1) * np.pi * i / n)
    num = 2 * q**(0.25) * pnum
    den = 1 + 2 * pden
    w[i]= num / den
```

Comment: `w` has just one index, which you declare at assignment. So index 1 and 2 don't exist, either initialize them to `0` or use `.append`.

Comment: I suspect you wanted `w = [0] *  ((n-1)//2)`, but you could also just set `w = []` and use `w.append(num/den)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line
w = [(n - 1) // 2]
Is creating a list of size 1 with the integer value 3 in it. You should review the way you created the array or create it empty and use the function append.

Answer (score 1):

Simple tracing shows the problem.  I inserted a trivial `print` to track the values.

```
den = 1 + 2 * pden
print(i, w)
w[i]= num / den
```

The output is

```
0 [3]
1 [0.0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Prune\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\so.py", line 14, in <module>
    w[i]= num / den
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

`w` is a single-element list, and you're trying to index the second element.  If you want to grow the list, you need to use `append` or `extend`.  Check your local tutorial for details on application.